# Remove duplicate object values so only unique values are returned (JS only) (No JQuery please)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dropdown

I have a unique situation. There are two dropdowns in the code below. The Names dropdown is filtered based on the selected tag from the Tags dropdown. The Names dropdown will return all values that belong to each tag in the object.

I want to filter down the tag values so only unique tags are returned.

With this, I still want to maintain the functionality of the Names dropdown so all names that belong to each tag are returned.

In short, tags must be unique (no duplicates) in the Tags dropdown while names in the Names dropdown keep their current functionality.

```js
let result = [
  {name: "some name", tag: "some tag"},
  {name: "some name1", tag: "some tag1"},
  {name: "some name1-2", tag: "some tag1"},  
  {name: "some name2", tag: "some tag2"},
  {name: "some name2-2", tag: "some tag2"}
];

//Generic function to fill a dropdown with options 
let populateDropDown = (params) => {
    params.optionsToPopulate.forEach(item => {
        params.element.add(new Option(item[`${params.text}`], item[`${params.text}`]))
    })
}

//Initialize tags dropdown
(function(){
  document.getElementById("tags").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    tagChanged(event);
  });

    let params = {
        optionsToPopulate:result,
        element:document.getElementById("tags"),
        id:"tag",
        text:"tag"
    }
    populateDropDown(params);

})();

//Tags dropdown change event.
let tagChanged = (event) => {   
    let tagValue = event.target.value;

    //filter the results based on the value of tags dropdown
    let optionsToAdd = result.filter(item => item.tag === tagValue);
    let names = document.getElementById("names");
    names.options.length=0;
    let params = {
        optionsToPopulate:optionsToAdd,
        element:names,
        id:"name",
        text:"name"
    }   
    populateDropDown(params);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  Tags: <select id="tags"></select> 

  <br><br><br>
  Names: <select id="names"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So keep track of what you insert and do not insert a duplicate. There are many ways to do it, the easiest is with Set()

```js
let result = [{
    name: "some name",
    tag: "some tag"
  },
  {
    name: "some name1",
    tag: "some tag1"
  },
  {
    name: "some name1-2",
    tag: "some tag1"
  },
  {
    name: "some name2",
    tag: "some tag2"
  },
  {
    name: "some name2-2",
    tag: "some tag2"
  }
];

//Generic function to fill a dropdown with options 
let populateDropDown = (params) => {
  let set = new Set()
  params.optionsToPopulate.forEach(item => {
    const txt = item[params.text];
    if (!set.has(txt)) {
      params.element.add(new Option(txt, txt))
       set.add(txt);
    }
  })
}

//Initialize tags dropdown
(function() {
  document.getElementById("tags").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    tagChanged(event);
  });

  let params = {
    optionsToPopulate: result,
    element: document.getElementById("tags"),
    id: "tag",
    text: "tag"
  }
  populateDropDown(params);

})();

//Tags dropdown change event.
let tagChanged = (event) => {
  let tagValue = event.target.value;

  //filter the results based on the value of tags dropdown
  let optionsToAdd = result.filter(item => item.tag === tagValue);
  let names = document.getElementById("names");
  names.options.length = 0;
  let params = {
    optionsToPopulate: optionsToAdd,
    element: names,
    id: "name",
    text: "name"
  }
  populateDropDown(params);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  Tags:
  <select id="tags"></select>

  <br><br><br> Names:
  <select id="names"></select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @epascarello I believe this is the answer I'm looking for. - If you don't mind,  could you add some more context to the updates you made to the populateDropDown function? This is my first time dealing with this problem and I really want a full understanding of what you did. I know that Set() will store unique values but just want a bit more on what happened with the other parts of the code. Would be happy to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: create a set. inside the loop. Am I in the set? No? Okay add the option, add to set. Next loop, am I am in set? Yes? well skip it.

Answer (score 0):

extract value of tag property and append to a list then use array.filter()

```
var arr = ["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag1","tag2","tag3"];

var filteredArray = arr.filter(function(item, pos){
  return arr.indexOf(item)== pos; 
});

console.log( filteredArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add duplicate detection in your `populateDropDown()`

```
//Generic function to fill a dropdown with options 
let populateDropDown = (params) => {
    console.log (params)
    let temp = [];
    params.optionsToPopulate.forEach(item => {
        if(temp.indexOf(item[`${params.text}`]) == -1){
            temp.push(item[`${params.text}`])
            params.element.add(new Option(item[`${params.text}`], item[`${params.text}`]))
        }
    })
}
```